# Easy to inspect Firestore response data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have a collection 'restaurants'.

In a 'restaurant' document, I store data I need to display information in my app's map, ie. opening time, location, etc.

I also store some more sensitive information related to a 'restaurant' on the same document. I need this information for my admin interface.

To reduce complexity, I want to keep this information stored on the same document 'restaurant'. So my question is, is it easy for someone to inspect the response from firestore when I fetch the restaurant doc for displaying the map. How easily could they find the 'sensitive' information from that response? If I inspect the console, the firebase response isn't that clear, so is it safe to do it this way?

Creating a separate collection to store the sensitive stuff is added complexity I don't necessarily want to introduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK always downloads complete documents. So that means that if you access Firestore from the client apps using the SDK, the client app will receive the complete document, including the sensitive data. Now you may choose to not display that data, but a malicious user will be able to access it, for example by replicating the calls that your app does.

If you don't want the sensitive information to be available to the users, you can:

- Store the sensitive information in a separate collection, that is then not accessible from the regular clients.
- Store the sensitive information in the same collection, but make the collection inaccessible from the clients. Then provide your own access API to the public data, for example with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). This API can access the collection through the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) (which bypasses the security rules), and only share the public data with the clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment Frank. That clears it up for me!